# Как разделить строку на части (добавить переводы строк по шаблону) в python?

Tags: python, форматирование

есть переменная со строкой нужно её переформатировать добавить ключи `'\n'`
и возможность `'[1]'` - изменить на смайл

```
row[2] = "[1] Place chicken in a medium bowl. Cover with lime juice and water. Set aside. [2] In a blender or food processor, place allspice, nutmeg, salt, brown sugar, thyme, ginger, black pepper and vegetable oil. Blend well, then mix in onions, green onions, garlic and habanero peppers until almost smooth. [3] Pour most of the blended marinade mixture into bowl with chicken, reserving a small amount to use as a basting sauce while cooking. Cover, and marinate in the refrigerator for at least 2 hours. [4] Preheat an outdoor grill for medium heat. [5] Brush grill grate with oil. Cook chicken slowly on the preheated grill. Turn frequently, basting often with remaining marinade mixture. Cook to desired doneness."
```

нужное форматирование :

```
""" [1] Place chicken in a medium bowl. Cover with lime juice and water. Set aside. \n
[2] In a blender or food processor, place allspice, nutmeg, salt, brown sugar, thyme, ginger, black pepper and vegetable oil. Blend well, then mix in onions, green onions, garlic and habanero peppers until almost smooth. \n 
[3] Pour most of the blended marinade mixture into bowl with chicken, reserving a small amount to use as a basting sauce while cooking. Cover, and marinate in the refrigerator for at least 2 hours. \n
[4] Preheat an outdoor grill for medium heat. \n 
[5] Brush grill grate with oil. Cook chicken slowly on the preheated grill. Turn frequently, basting often with remaining marinade mixture. Cook to desired doneness.\n"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом, ответ дан, есть еще один вариант:

```
import re

def myreplace(match):
   return "\n{}".format(match.group())

old_s = "[1] a [2] b [3] c"
p = re.compile("(\[\d+\])")
new_s =  p.sub(myreplaсe, old_s).strip()
print new_s
>>> [1] a
>>> [2] b
>>> [3] c
```

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

---

То же с заменой на А., В., ...

```
import re

l = ['', 'A.', 'B.', 'C.']

def myreplace(match):
   s = int(match.group()[1:-1])
   return "\n{}".format(l[s])

old_s = "[1] a [2] b [3] c"
p = re.compile("(\[\d+\])")
print p.sub(myreplace, old_s)
```

Только аккуратно с длиной списка `l` (либо меняем `l[s]` на `somefunction(s)`, которая меняет число на нужную строку), вывод:

```
A. a
B. b
C. c
```

Comment: отлично! а есть требуется заменить [1].. на A. B. C. ... или на какие-то другие символы ?

Comment: @Surfer, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Пусть содержимое строки в `s`, т.е. `s = row[2]`,
тогда

```
s1 = re.sub(r"(\[\d+\])", "\n\\1", s)
s1 = s1.replace("\n[1]", "[1]")
```

и в `s1` будет отформатированная строка.

Comment: Как вариант, вместо 2-й строки `s1 = s1.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

если имеется в виду один элемент массива показывать так как нужно, то так:
   `row[2] = "[1] Place chicken in a medium bowl. Cover with lime juice and water. Set aside.\n [2] In a blender or food processor, place allspice, nutmeg, salt, brown sugar, thyme, ginger, black pepper and vegetable oil. Blend well, then mix in onions, green onions, garlic and habanero peppers until almost smooth.\n [3] Pour most of the blended marinade mixture into bowl with chicken, reserving a small amount to use as a basting sauce while cooking. Cover, and marinate in the refrigerator for at least 2 hours.\n [4] Preheat an outdoor grill for medium heat.\n [5] Brush grill grate with oil. Cook chicken slowly on the preheated grill. Turn frequently, basting often with remaining marinade mixture. Cook to desired doneness."`
Если каждый пункт это элемент массива, то лучше строки разнести по элементам